# ExoPlayer and start / pause / seekTo commands

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller, exoplayer

I am trying to use `ExoPlayer`, as opposed to `MediaPlayer` and I can't seem to figure it out...

`MediaPlayer` has `.start()` / `.pause()` commands... and I can just `seekTo(1287)` and it automatically starts playing...

How do I do this with `ExoPlayer`? I have tried to do `seekTo(1287)` but it doesn't start playing after... I have also added `.setPlayWhenReady(true)` after that, and still no luck...

I am able to `.stop()`... but I can't get it to start playing again after that unless I `.prepare()` again... but I don't think I should have to do that between every pause and play.

I am using my own controls and methods opposed to `MediaController` like in the ExoPlayer Demo... I can't quite see how the controls are implemented...

Any suggestions anyone?

**Edit:**

OK, I figured out pause and start...

```
.setPlayWhenReady(true) // start
.setPlayWhenReady(false) // pause
```

But I'm still having problems with the tracking... `.seekTo` works intermittently... sometimes it works... but other times I get this error:

```
E/AudioTrack: AudioTrack::set : Exit
```

(and it only gets to the buffer state... doesn't quite get to "ready"...

Answer (score 49):

The [official example of the `PlayerControl`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/util/PlayerControl.java) in the **ExoPlayer** source code do exactly what you asked:

> ```
> public class PlayerControl implements MediaPlayerControl {
>
>   private final ExoPlayer exoPlayer;
>
>   public PlayerControl(ExoPlayer exoPlayer) {
>     this.exoPlayer = exoPlayer;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean canPause() {
>     return true;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean canSeekBackward() {
>     return true;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean canSeekForward() {
>     return true;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public int getAudioSessionId() {
>     throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public int getBufferPercentage() {
>     return exoPlayer.getBufferedPercentage();
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public int getCurrentPosition() {
>     return exoPlayer.getDuration() == ExoPlayer.UNKNOWN_TIME ? 0
>         : (int) exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public int getDuration() {
>     return exoPlayer.getDuration() == ExoPlayer.UNKNOWN_TIME ? 0
>         : (int) exoPlayer.getDuration();
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean isPlaying() {
>     return exoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady();
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void start() {
>     exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void pause() {
>     exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void seekTo(int timeMillis) {
>     long seekPosition = exoPlayer.getDuration() == ExoPlayer.UNKNOWN_TIME ? 0
>         : Math.min(Math.max(0, timeMillis), getDuration());
>     exoPlayer.seekTo(seekPosition);
>   }
>
> }
> ```

If you are experiencing strange behaviors during the seek operation, it may be due to you particular stream/file type. I can suggest you to take a look at the [base implementation](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/ExoPlayerImplInternal.java) of the ExoPlayer and, eventually, report any [issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues) on Github.

Comment: github links are dead

Comment: ExoPlayer changed a lot in v2. Couldn't find the updated GH link for PlayerControl.java, but here's the link for the base implementation: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayerImplInternal.java

Comment: ExoPlayer.UNKNOWN_TIME -> com.google.android.exoplayer2.C.TIME_UNSET

Comment: link are dead.. please fix this.

Comment: how to add this class to my xoplayer object?

Answer (score 11):

Here's how [the example code](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java#L306) does it for Exoplayer 2:

```
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

[starts playback, (`false` stops)](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.html#setPlayWhenReady-boolean-)

> If the player is already in the ready state then this method can be used to pause and resume playback.

To seek, they use

> ```
> boolean haveStartPosition = startWindow != C.INDEX_UNSET;
> if (haveStartPosition) {
>   player.seekTo(startWindow, startPosition);
> }
> player.prepare(mediaSource, !haveStartPosition, false);
> ```

So it seems you need to [`prepare`](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.html#prepare-com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource-boolean-boolean-) after the `seekTo`.

Comment: this is latest answer according to latest exoplayer release .