# ExoPlayer set commands cant find UNKNOWN_TIME

Tags: java, android, duration, exoplayer2.x

i'm trying to set the commands of exoPlayer but i don't know how to set the

```
getDuration();
getCurrentPosition();
```

I found this but what i have to set on `UNKNOWN_TIME` cause its telling me cannot resolve symbol `UNKNOWN_TIME`

```
@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return exoPlayer.getDuration() == ExoPlayer.UNKNOWN_TIME ? 0
            : (int) exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return exoPlayer.getDuration() == ExoPlayer.UNKNOWN_TIME ? 0
            : (int) exoPlayer.getDuration();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: not helping me ..exoplayer is a library and when i do exoplayer.UNKNOWN_TIME should be there but isnt there

Comment: im playing an mp3 by url and on seekbar i have to set exoPlayer.getDuration(); but first i have to set the commands

Comment: like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926483/exoplayer-and-start-pause-seekto-commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ExoPlayer 2.0 You should use `C.TIME_UNSET` constant (from com.google.android.exoplayer2 package) instead of `ExoPlayer.UNKNOWN_TIME` (see this description for [`getDuration()`](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.html#getDuration) method for ExoPlayer 2.0.