# how to implement Play & Pause controller ExoPlayer 2

Tags: android, video, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to use ExoPlayer 2 in my app to play video in recyclerview when I click on videoview or SimpleExoPlayerView video should play and if I clcik again it should be pause 
Now the problem is I'm unable to find Player.Controler class in ExoPlayer2 so I can play and pause the video or any other way if you can guide me please that how I can implement controller to play & pause the video.... 
I have used this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926483/exoplayer-and-start-pause-seekto-commands) also but didn't get some thing cool

Answer (score 0):

You can use : 
player.setPlayWhenReady(true) to play the source when it's ready or you can pause with :
player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
I suggest you read this guide carefully : https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html

Comment: Well my friend I have searched so far and haven't find anything which can play my video like instagram r is there any player if you can recommend me which can play a video like insta gram or any library